# What movie is this?

Tags: visual, knowledge

A 2 year old built this and I couldn't resist taking a photo of it.
It reminded me of a scene from a well known movie.

[image]

**Which movie is the scene from?**

A little hint:

> Although not entirely intentionally (the author is really young) this picture contains some clever clues on what movie I think about.

Comment: Too easy. [Even I know this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/121309/31394).

Comment: @randal'thor hahaha :D consider migrating it to movies.SE...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It looks like a scene from

> Back to the Future 3
>
>  [image]

Comment: This answer was the first to be correct, so it is the accepted one.

Answer (score 15):

The answer is clearly

> Cars

Because

> That is Lightning McQueen. He is pulling the train which is similar to the moment in the movie Cars when he has to pull the paver to pave the road. The train track is difficult terrain for the car, just like the unpaved road was for the car. The train is similar to the paver because it is a heavy thing you wouldn't expect for a car to pull.
>  The clock is symbolic. The first time McQueen paved the road he did it too quickly and messed up -- the second time he had to take his time. McQueen is literally bringing "time" with him in the picture.

A picture of the scene I am referring to:

> [image]

This is correct and not a joke.

Comment: How does the clock fit in?

Comment: @IanMacDonald I've updated my answer.

Comment: @CaptainMan Well, this is not the intended answer. You took the picture too metaphorically, but nice try.

Comment: @oleslaw I know it's not correct, I just thought it would be fun! I could tell what it was immediately by looking at it (weird that they made such a spot on model of it). :)

Comment: This is the winner.

Comment: I haven't seen the film, but I have read the book.

Comment: @oleslaw you mean too literally?

Answer (score 9):

Is this

> Back to the Future 3, specifically the finale where the train is pushing the car up to the correct speed.

The other clue I noted was the

> clock on the car, which points to the Hill Valley clock tower, which was a focal point of the first movie.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like

> the [Locomotive 131](http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Locomotive_131) from the movie [Back to the future III](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future_Part_III) :
>
>  [image]

It allowed

> the Delorean to reach 88 mph, and enter temporal displacement before it crashed into a wooden "End of Track" barrier.

Also:

> The clock on the picture is a reference to the time, which is the leitmotiv of the saga.

Answer (score 5):

> Toy reminds me of a scene from Antman.

Comment: How does it remind you of Ant man?!

Comment: @AJL The fight scene between Ant Man and Yellow Jacket took place in a child's bedroom. [Thomas the Tank Engine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=muYbXyYxd5E) was even involved.

Comment: This was my first thought, but it's clearly wrong. Others have already guessed the correct answer.